# Como obtener datos de un formulario con JSF?

Tags: java, html, formularios, jsf

Tengo el siguiente formulario y quiero recuperar los datos que se envien

```html
<f:view>
    <h:form id="form_pruebas" class="form-horizontal">
        <p:panel>
            <div class="form-group">

                <h:outputLabel for="intentosAp" value="Intentos de aplicación" style="display: inline-block width: 70px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <h:inputText id="intentosAp" value="#{configuraciones.datosEntrada.intentosAplicacion}" style="width: 60px;" required="true" maxlength="2"/>

     

                <h:outputLabel for="intentosExi" value="Intentos exitosos:" style="display: inline-block width: 25px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <h:inputText id="intentosExi" value="#{configuraciones.datosEntrada.intentosExitosos}" style="width: 60px;" required="true" maxlength="3"/>

     

                <h:outputLabel for="intentosFall" value="Intentos fallidos" style="display: inline-block width: 50px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                <h:inputText id="intentosFall" style="width: 60px;" value="#{configuraciones.datosEntrada.intentosFallidos}" required="true" maxlength="3"/>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <h:commandButton value="Enviar" type="submit" action="#{datosEntrada.obtenerParametros}"/>
            </div>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
</f:view>
```

Tengo la clase **DatosEntrada** donde estan mapeados los campos

```html
public class DatosEntrada{

    @Getter @Setter private String intentosAplicacion;
    @Getter @Setter private String intentosExitosos;
    @Getter @Setter private String  intentosFallidos;

}
```

y la clase Configuraciones donde quiero que vaya toda la logica, no se como recuperar los datos que envian, es la primera vez que trabajo con JSF

```html
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Configuraciones{

    private DatosEntrada datosEntrada;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initView(){
    
    }

    public void obtenerParametros(){
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la clase Configuraciones deberías agregar un setter para *datosEntrada*. En el método *obtenerParametros* ya podrías usar *datosEntrada*.

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Configuraciones{

  private DatosEntrada datosEntrada;

  public void setDatosEntrada(DatosEntrada datosEntrada) {
   this.datosEntrada = datosEntrada;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void initView(){
  }

  public void obtenerParametros() {
   // Usar los datos, ejemplo:
   datosEntrada.getIntentosExitosos();
  }
}
```

Además, en el formulario deberías usar el bean *configuraciones*:

```
<h:commandButton value="Enviar" type="submit" action="#{configuraciones.obtenerParametros}"/>
```